# Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'List.min().compareTo(500)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'List.min()'

Tags: kotlin

The following functions produces error. How to use let() or similar null check functions inside a if/for statement.

Here is my code:

```
fun main() {
    var List = listOf<Int>(201, 53 ,5 ,556 ,70 , 9999)
    var budget: Int = 500
    if(List.min() < 500) { // this line produces the error
        println("Yes you can buy from this shop")
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
Operator call corresponds to a dot-qualified call 'List.min().compareTo(500)' which is not allowed on a nullable receiver 'List.min()'.
```

Help me with nullable types. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The question here is: **what do you want to happen if your list is empty?**

If a list has one or more items, and those items are comparable, then you can always find a minimum.  (It doesn't have to be unique.)  But **if the list has *no* items, then there *is* no minimum.**  So what do you want to happen then?  Do you want to continue with a ‘default’ value?  Or skip that block?  Or something else?

If you want a default value, then you can use the elvis operator:

```
if ((list.minOrNull() ?: 0) < 500)
    println("Yes you can buy from this shop")
```

That substitutes the value `0` if the list is empty.  (It doesn't have to be zero; any value will do.  In fact, this can work with any type as long as it's Comparable.)

Or you could do an explicit check for the list being empty:

```
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    // Do something else
} else if (list.minOrNull()!! < 500)
    println("Yes you can buy from this shop")
```

The `!!` non-null assertion operator works here, but it's a code smell.  (It's easy to miss when you're changing surrounding code; it could then throw a NullPointerException.)  So it's safer to handle the null.  Perhaps the most idiomatic way is with `let()`:

```
list.minOrNull().let {
    if (it == null) {
        // Do something else
    } else if (it < 500)
        println("Yes you can buy from this shop")
}
```

(The `<` check is allowed there, because by that point the compiler knows `it` can't be null.)

Or if you just want to avoid the check entirely, use a `?.` safe-call so that `let()` is only called on a non-null value:

```
list.minOrNull()?.let {
    if (it < 500)
        println("Yes you can buy from this shop")
}
```

Comment: Suppose my list is such : (23, 23, 23, 23) . All items are equal so there is no question of minimum value. So the minOrNull() function will return null. When it will return null I want to skip the code block

Comment: And I tried using minOrNull but the same error appeared.

Comment: `minOrNull()` finds _a_ minimum item.  It doesn't have to be unique.  As [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-or-null.html) says, it returns null if there are _no_ items.  If they're all the same, it could return _any_ of them; it won't return null as long as there's at least one item. -- What error, and on what line?  Please confirm you're either doing an explicit null check, or using a safe call.

Comment: Oh that was what I was not understanding . Actually I thought that Min will return null if all the elements in the list are same . But thats not the case. Anyways thank you